# Nodemon watching folder not working, only works when watching files

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I am trying to restart a script once any file in a folder changes: I want to run index.js every time the test folder gets changed (either file a or file b). I want to do this because in my other project, the index.js file will read the content from the folder and show some statistics. I want to re-display the data once the user changes content.

The index.js contains a single line of code: `console.log(123);`. I used the command `npx nodemon index.js --watch test` but it does not work - when changing file a or file b, no content is logged to the console. However, it does work when running `npx nodemon index.js --watch data` (but I need to watch for folder changes rather than a single file). Does anyone know what is going wrong with my approach? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I did not execute the command inside `test`, i.e., `index.js` is in the cwd. Also note that `data` is not in the `test` folder